# Crystal Report with total divided by product

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I'm creating a report (VS2019 and CR 13.0.4) and I can't understand how totals can be obtained as in the example in the figure.
[total example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwFQ5.png)
My report has a typed dataset as its data source.
I could also generate a dataset with totals without any problems.
Anyone have any idea how this can be done?
Thank you very much.
Beppe

Now I can only get the grand total of the amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is to insert a CrossTab in the Report Footer.
There are several other ways, including inserting a subreport.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion.
I tried the crosstab and it's the solution to my problem!
Good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your report data based on the field where you want subtotals, then Create summary fields within the group footer or group header sections to calculate subtotals.